# Structural and behavioral modelling of the possibility of unknown (or pending variable) objects rather than concrete ones

Tags: java, design-patterns

In the following, I provide an abstract description of my problem, as it will be more complicated if I provide the context and the specific code.

I have a Class `Specification`. A file reader accesses specific nested specifications from a file and furnishes a `Specification` instance correspondingly. The file may contain incomplete specifications, i.e. some values are to be bound later (for example, from a user input).

```
class Specification{
    Criteria spec1;
    AnotherCriteria spec2;
    ...
}
```

Now consider the interface:

```
Interface Criteria {
    criteriaMethod1();
    criteriaMethod2();
}
```

And consider the implementing class:

```
class ConcreteCriteria1 implements Criteria{
    someDataMember;
    @Overrride
    criteriaMethod1(){
        // some implementation goes here
    }
    @Overrride
    criteriaMethod2(){
        // some implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Now let's consider a class responsible for performing some specific tasks depending on a `Criteria` passed:

```
class WorkExcuter {
    doSomeWork(Criteria criteria);
}
```

I have a case, in such the `criteria` passed to `doSomeWork` is **unknown**, for example, in a waiting state to get some input from the user. This unknown state forces some specific additional attributes, for example, it's a maximum lenght of characters, an identifier, a waiting time, etc. To model that, let's consider that we have:

```
Interface ReuqiredInput {
    reuqiredInputMethod1();
}
```

**Problem:**

I want an '*intelligent*' way (e.g. some design pattern) to make both, `Specification` (in `spec1` data memebr) and `doSomeWork` accept `ReuqiredInput` instead of Criteria when the state is unknown as described. So they should accept both cases: either `Criteria`, or `RequiredInput`.

**Possible ways around:**

- Make `ConcreteCriteria1` implement `ReuqiredInput`, in addition to `Criteria`; i.e., having a single concrete class implementing both interfaces; but then, I will have my concrete class as an ugly **`XOR`** between two different sets of elements that have nothing to do with each other and it has to have a method that figures out which set of elements is filled (to avoid exceptions as the other set will be null), and it complicates the access via the implemented interfaces.
- Overload `doSomeWork`; so that:

  ```
  class WorkExcuter {
      doSomeWork(Criteria criteria);
      doSomeWork(RequiredInput input);
  }
  ```

  But that solves the behavior part, but not the structural part, i.e. How to convince `Specification` that it can accept data member in `sepc1` of type `RequiredInput` instead of `Criteria`?

Answer (score 0):

Your Criteria doesn't have different data in different states, it has whatever data members it needs for its calculations and they might be unset when it is waiting for user input; there are various options to ensure it receives user input before proceeding to the main calculations. For example

- criteriaMethod1() etc. can request user input interactively if needed (presumably, the first time they are called). No RequiredInput objects are used. Likely to be messy because it places user interface code in a business logic component like Criteria.
- criteriaMethod1() etc. can return an error if called with an incomplete state, then their caller is expected to ask them what input they require (with some Criteria method returning RequiredInput objects). The caller uses RequiredInput objects to obtain information, passes that information to the Criteria, and then criteriaMethod1() etc. can be called successfully.
- even better, Criteria objects are created only when all needed data are available, and they are never in an invalid waiting-for-input state. For the case of combining an incomplete specification file with user inputs, this probably involves specific classes to represent the content of the configuration file and a module that, given the configuration file, asks the user for missing information and creates Criteria. The rest of the program, the part that *uses* Criteria, only sees complete ones. RequiredInput objects might be useful as an intermediate representation of what the configuration file leaves unspecified.